# Azure ML Error: You must provide an InferenceConfig when deploying a model with model_framework set to AutoML

Tags: python-3.x, azure, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to deploy an Azure ML AutoML generated model with an ML Notebook (script is shortened for brevity):

```
automl_settings = {
    "experiment_timeout_minutes": 20,
    "primary_metric": 'AUC_weighted',
    "max_concurrent_iterations": 8, 
    "max_cores_per_iteration": -1,
    "enable_dnn": False,
    "enable_early_stopping": True,
    "validation_size": 0.3,
    "verbosity": logging.INFO,
}

automl_config = AutoMLConfig(task = 'classification',
                             debug_log = 'automl_errors.log',
                             compute_target=compute_target,
                             blacklist_models=['LogisticRegression','MultinomialNaiveBayes','BernoulliNaiveBayes','LinearSVM','DecisionTree','RandomForest','ExtremeRandomTrees','LightGBM','KNN','SVM','StackEnsemble','VotingEnsemble'],
                             training_data=train_dataset,
                             label_column_name=target_column_name,
                             **automl_settings
                            )

automl_run = experiment.submit(automl_config, show_output=True)

best_run, fitted_model = automl_run.get_output()
best_run_metrics = best_run.get_metrics()

children = list(automl_run.get_children(recursive=True))
summary_df = pd.DataFrame(index=['run_id', 'run_algorithm',
                                    'primary_metric', 'Score'])
goal_minimize = False
for run in children:
    if('run_algorithm' in run.properties and 'score' in run.properties):
        summary_df[run.id] = [run.id, run.properties['run_algorithm'],
                                run.properties['primary_metric'],
                                float(run.properties['score'])]
        if('goal' in run.properties):
            goal_minimize = run.properties['goal'].split('_')[-1] == 'min'

    summary_df = summary_df.T.sort_values(
        'Score',
        ascending=goal_minimize).drop_duplicates(['run_algorithm'])
    summary_df = summary_df.set_index('run_algorithm')
    
    best_dnn_run_id = summary_df['run_id'].iloc[0]
    best_dnn_run = Run(experiment, best_dnn_run_id)

model_dir = 'Model' # Local folder where the model will be stored temporarily
if not os.path.isdir(model_dir):
    os.mkdir(model_dir)
    
best_run.download_file('outputs/model.pkl', model_dir + '/model.pkl')

# Register the model
model_name = best_run.properties['model_name']

model_path=os.path.join("./outputs",'model.pkl')

description = 'My Model'
model = best_run.register_model(model_name=model_name, model_path=model_path, model_framework='AutoML', description = description, tags={'env': 'sandbox'})

# Deploy the Model

service_name = 'my-ml-service'
service = Model.deploy(ws, service_name, [model], overwrite=True)

service.wait_for_deployment(show_output=True)
```

Everything appears to run fine until I try to deploy the model:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- UserErrorException                        Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-48-5c72d1613c28> in <module>
      3 service_name = 'my-service'
      4 
----> 5 service = Model.deploy(ws, service_name, [model], overwrite=True)
      6 
      7 

/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azureml/core/model.py in deploy(workspace, name, models, inference_config, deployment_config, deployment_target, overwrite)    1577               logger=module_logger)    1578 
-> 1579             return Model._deploy_no_code(workspace, name, models, deployment_config, deployment_target, overwrite)    1580     1581         # Environment-based webservice.

/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azureml/core/model.py in _deploy_no_code(workspace, name, models, deployment_config, deployment_target, overwrite)    1795         :rtype: azureml.core.Webservice    1796         """
-> 1797         environment_image_request = build_and_validate_no_code_environment_image_request(models)    1798   1799         return Model._deploy_with_environment_image_request(workspace, name, environment_image_request,

/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azureml/_model_management/_util.py in build_and_validate_no_code_environment_image_request(models)    1180         raise UserErrorException('You must provide an InferenceConfig when deploying a model with model_framework '    1181  'set to {}. Default environments are only provided for these frameworks: {}.'
-> 1182                                  .format(model.model_framework, Model._SUPPORTED_FRAMEWORKS_FOR_NO_CODE_DEPLOY))    1183     1184    
# Only specify the model IDs; MMS will provide the environment, driver program, etc.

UserErrorException: UserErrorException:     Message: You must provide an InferenceConfig when deploying a model with model_framework set to AutoML. Default environments are only provided for these frameworks: ['Onnx', 'ScikitLearn', 'TensorFlow'].     InnerException None     ErrorResponse  {
    "error": {
        "code": "UserError",
        "message": "You must provide an InferenceConfig when deploying a model with model_framework set to AutoML. Default environments are only provided for these frameworks: ['Onnx', 'ScikitLearn', 'TensorFlow']."
    }
```

When deploying an AutoML generated model from the Azure Machine Learning Studio, I am not prompted to provide an entry script or dependencies file (or an InferenceConfig). Is there a way to configure this with the Python SDK so that I can "no code deploy" an AutoML generated model?  Is there something wrong in my code?  Hope you can help.

Comment: Is there any preference for using `Model.deploy()`? This [tutorial](https://benalexkeen.com/using-azure-automl-and-aml-for-assessing-multiple-models-and-deployment/) walks through deploying the service from a packaged image starting from an AutoML model. I haven't used `deploy()` from model directly to help on the issue above

Comment: No, no preference, I just want it to deploy successfully without having to provide an inferenceConfig etc.

Comment: then I think the tutorial attached above would help you get to an endpoint

Comment: checking it out...

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can rely on "no code" deployment in your scenario, because AutoML may find the best solution is from a framework that is not yet supported by "no code" deployment.

If it helps, you can create the `InferenceConfig` from your `Run`:

```
environment = best_run.get_context().get_environment()
inference_config = InferenceConfig(entry_script='score.py', environment=environment)
```

Comment: I'm getting the error AttributeError: '_OfflineRun' object has no attribute 'get_environment'.

Comment: When i do best_run.get_environment() that returns Environment(Name: AutoML-AzureML-AutoML,
Version: Autosave_2020-07-18T14:23:19Z_433bd586), but the deployment still creates an unhealthy endpoint that is unreachable.